# urllib and 'HTTPError: Bad Request'

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I need to access a Twitter user's timeline as a JSON string and return the first 250 chars.

Twitter1.py:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import twurl
import ssl

TWITTER_URL = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json'

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

while True:
    print('')
    acct = input('Enter Twitter Account:')
    if (len(acct) < 1): break
    url = twurl.augment(TWITTER_URL,
                        {'screen_name': acct, 'count': '2'})
    print('Retrieving', url)
    connection = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx)
    data = connection.read().decode()
    print(data[:250])
    headers = dict(connection.getheaders())
    print('Remaining', headers['x-rate-limit-remaining'])
```

An error related to urllib occurs in output:

```
Enter Twitter Account:jack
...
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\User\...\twitter1.py", line 18, in <module>
    connection = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx)

  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)

  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)

  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Bad Request
```

I cannot figure out the source of the issue. The syntax appears correct and the correct API information was entered into a separate python file 'hidden.py'. twurl and oauth were imported from twurl.py and oauth.py to access the data (included below). hidden.py simply returns my API info in JSON within a function oauth() and oauth is well known so it is also excluded here. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

twurl.py:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import oauth
import hidden

def augment(url, parameters):
    secrets = hidden.oauth()
    consumer = oauth.OAuthConsumer(secrets['consumer_key'],
                                   secrets['consumer_secret'])
    token = oauth.OAuthToken(secrets['token_key'], secrets['token_secret'])

    oauth_request = oauth.OAuthRequest.from_consumer_and_token(consumer,
                    token=token, http_method='GET', http_url=url,
                    parameters=parameters)
    oauth_request.sign_request(oauth.OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(),
                               consumer, token)
    return oauth_request.to_url()
```

Comment: Bad Request is indicating that your request doesn't contains all required params. Can you check if your token is getting forwarded
Can you please check if using `twurl authorize --consumer-key KEY --consumer-secret SECRET` you are able to login.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how exactly this is done?

Comment: run this in terminal `python3 -m twurl authorize --consumer-key KEY --consumer-secret SECRET` pass KEY and SECRET of twitter that you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow up: was resolved soon after I posted, the issue was regarding a domain being blocked by an antivirus filter.